# Canonical urls: Htaccess creates 403 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to do a "www" redirects to non WWW for my site so I have canonical urls.

To do this, I have created the following .htaccess file:

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, it creates the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

How can I get the www to redirect to non-www? I know I can use the canonical urls tag, but I would like to do it a more global level, than per a page.

My site is just a static HTMl site (it doesn't use PHP)

This is my site set up:
public_html/hosted/other/[siteroot]

The .htaccess is in [siteroot]

Comment: @anubhava This is my site set up: public_html/hosted/other/[siteroot]

The .htaccess is in [siteroot] (I have updated first post)

Comment: @anubhava I get the 403 error regardless if I enter it with or without Http:// or www.

Comment: @anubhava Same 403 error. I if delete the .htaccess error, it works, but then the non-www/www redirect doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava Sadly, commenting out the lines does not work.

Comment: Well I cannot reall guess the problem. You should check Apache error.log file for reason of 403